# Как получить первый текст внутри тега?

Tags: python-3.x, beautiful-soup

Есть объект супа

```
<span class="nowrap">
     2 633
    <span class="currency rub">q</span>
</span>
```

делаю следующее:

```
price = item.find('span', class_='nowrap')
price_x = price.text.strip()
print(price_x)
```

Выводит:
2 633 q

Подскажите, как вывести без q

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.text дает нам все строки внутри тега сцепленными. Вместо этого надо  использовать next_element:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'lxml')
price = soup.find('span', class_='nowrap')
next_element = price.next_element
print(next_element.strip())
```

И тогда получаем нужный результат: '2 633'

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]